# echo key and value of an array without and with loop

Tags: php, arrays, echo

This is an array i have

```
<?php
$page['Home']='index.html';
$page['Service']='services.html';
?>
```

How do i get to echo something like this for individual one like

```
Home is at index.html
```

and again how can i do this through a loop and echo all?

Comment: see [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach).

Comment: http://www.google.de/search?q=php+loop+array and http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php . Reading documentation helps a lot.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
foreach($page as $key => $value) {
  echo "$key is at $value";
}
```

For 'without loop' version I'll just ask "why?"

Comment: This is fine... just wanted to know if it possible to get a value individually by referring it to as 0 or 1 etc... I have just started with these stuffs. Thank You very much!!

Comment: that's a very common thing actually, to address an array items individually.

Comment: Oh, OK. I understood your question as 'how to echo all key-value elements from an array without using a loop' - which would be silly thing to do IMHO (unless using array_walk like KennyTM did).

Comment: If your array consist only of one key and one value, it would be convenient not to have to use the loop. If you don't know the key:

`key($page).' is at  '.$page[key($page)];`

Answer (score 16):

Without a loop, just for the kicks of it...

---

You can either convert the array to a non-associative one, by doing:

```
$page = array_values($page);
```

And then acessing each element by it's zero-based index:

```
echo $page[0]; // 'index.html'
echo $page[1]; // 'services.html'
```

---

Or you can use a slightly more complicated version:

```
$value = array_slice($page, 0, 1);

echo key($value); // Home
echo current($value); // index.html

$value = array_slice($page, 1, 1);

echo key($value); // Service
echo current($value); // services.html
```

Answer (score 8):

If you must not use a loop (why?), [you could use `array_walk`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php),

```
function printer($v, $k) {
   echo "$k is at $v\n";
}

array_walk($page, "printer");
```

See http://www.ideone.com/aV5X6.

Answer (score 6):

Echo key and value of an array without and with loop

```
$array = array(
            'kk6NFKK'=>'name',
            'nnbDDD'=>'claGg',
            'nnbDDD'=>'kaoOPOP',
            'nnbDDD'=>'JWIDE4',
            'nnbDDD'=>'lopO'
         );


print_r(each($array));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [1] => name
    [value] => name
    [0] => kk6NFKK
    [key] => kk6NFKK
)
```

Comment: The `each()` function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.  Source: [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php)

Answer (score 5):

for the first question

```
$key = 'Home';
echo $key." is at ".$page[$key];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function displayArrayValue($array,$key) {
   if (array_key_exists($key,$array)) echo "$key is at ".$array[$key];
}

displayArrayValue($page, "Service");
```

Answer (score 2):

How to echo key and value of an array without and with loop

```
$keys = array_keys($page);
implode(',',$keys);
echo $keys[0].' is at '.$page['Home'];
```

Answer (score 1):

My version without a loop would be like this:

```
echo implode(
    "\n", 
    array_map(
         function ($k, $v) { 
             return "$k is at $v"; 
         }, 
         array_keys($page), 
         array_values($page)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function for a change;) I use it to output the media information for videos etc elements of which can use nested array / attributes.

```
function custom_print_array($arr = array()) {
    $output = '';
    foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
        if(is_array($val)){
            $output .= '<li><strong>' . ucwords(str_replace('_',' ', $key)) . ':</strong><ul class="children">' . custom_print_array($val) . '</ul>' . '</li>';
        }
        else {
            $output .=  '<li><strong>' . ucwords(str_replace('_',' ', $key)) . ':</strong> ' . $val . '</li>';
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_walk($v, function(&$value, $key) {
   echo $key . '--'. $value;
 });
```

Learn more about [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk)

Answer (score -2):

You can try following code:

```
foreach ($arry as $key => $value) 
{
      echo $key;
      foreach ($value as  $val) 
      {
         echo $val; 
      }
}
```