# How to get the key and value from associative array into a one dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

eg.

```
 ['key' => 'value', 'key2' => 'value2']
```

to

```
 ['key', 'value', 'key2', 'value2']
```

Also, how do I get comma separated string from said array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [echo key and value of an array without and with loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406726/echo-key-and-value-of-an-array-without-and-with-loop)

Comment: https://3v4l.org/pqPVs lol

Comment: Your question is Unclear and Too Broad because you have not attempted to code a solution yourself.  We don't know if you want a string with double-quote-wrapped comma-separated values, or if you actually want a 1-dimensional array.

Comment: Wanted it as 1-dimensional array or you can say comma seperated string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do something like that

```
 foreach ($yourArray as $key => $value) {  
    echo $key . "&nbsp;" . $value;
 }
```

It will echo string `"key, value, key2, value2"`

Comment: No, it echoes `ayour-namebyour-subjectbsubjectbyour-message` once you fix the syntax error.